# How to match same column between system data table and excel in UiPath RPA

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, rows, rpa, uipath

I'd like to use RPA to copy the values from the system back to Excel by mapping the same column names.

***Get Text*** → ***Assign***

***Data Scraping*** → ***Write into***

However, I've used these two methods as above and they all turned out wrong.

Here're the steps as follow:

Every time RPA is in the system and the sheet shows up:

1. Find the null in "**Person in charge**" column and copy related value in "**Serial number**" to the blank in the system.
2. Copy the three values ("**U.K.**, **ddF Section**, and **XYZ Section**") and paste to the row related with columns matching between two data tables. And it bases on ***Serial number*** = F38290W5800013
3. Write "RPA" in "**Person in charge**" which also bases on ***Serial number*** = F38290W5800013

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas regarding these?

Many Thanks~

Comment: For step 1, use the read range activity to grab all of the data into a datatable which you can then iterate over to find a blank, filter to find a blank, or use a .net command to find the blanks.  Once you have the row with the blank Person In Charge, use the serial number to lookup the System and find the right entry. For Step 2, once you have the right entry you can read the correct cells to get the information to insert into the blank row you got in step 1, along with "RPA" into the name cell.  Step 3, Write range will put your updated datatable back into Excel - all done!

Comment: Are these two sets of information in 1) two data tables, 2) two Excel files, or 3) An ERP system and an Excel file? The answer would depend on how each of the data is being interacted with.